# How to read block propagation delay from ethstats.net?

Tags: go-ethereum, blocks, transaction-propagation

I am wondering what is the average (or mdeian) time it takes to propagate a block in the Ethereum blockchain?

I found ethstats.net provides a cummlative graph for block block propagation but do not know how to extract the average or median time from it?

Is there any easy way to check it?